# Exception information:Message: Invalid controller specified (index)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, frameworks

I inherited the maintaining of a `php 1.0` website that uses the `zend framework`. And I have really no experience with this framework. I changed the wording on a page and received the following error message. I have know idea where to begin fixing this problem.

```
Exception information:Message: Invalid controller specified (index) , 

#0 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): 
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), 
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))#1 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library
/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()

#2 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Application.php(366): 
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()

#3 /var/www/ispadmin/public/index.php(47): Zend_Application->run()

#4 {main} array: 'module' => string 'agreements' (length=10), 'controller' => string 'index' (length=5), 'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
```

Please help, Yvette.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create class Agreements_IndexController with method

`public function indexAction() { }`

and put it in here `application/modules/agreements/controllers/IndexController.php`. And don't forget to create view file, `application/modules/agreements/views/sctipts/index/index.phtml`.

With basic config it should help.